# How to remove culture from ASP.NET Core paths?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, url-rewriting

I am not using ASP.NET Core's internal i18n support. I am building my own mechanism.

I want to insert the selected culture inside the URL, similar to Next.js.

Thus, for the **About** page, I can have three paths:

1. `/about`
2. `/en/about`
3. `/ar/about`

But now I'm stuck at removing those `/en` and `/ar` from path segments.

Many examples I saw include URL rewrite and they are talking about the web server (IIS or Nginx).

Can I do it without them? Is it possible to rewrite URL internally in ASP.NET Core's middleware?

Comment: ASP.NET Core has rewrite middleware, yes.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, any link that can get me started?

Comment: Searching "rewrite middleware c#" on Google got me this as the first hit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, I saw the same link before asking this question. Where on that page is there an example of URL rewrite without IIS or Nginx? That's why I asked.

Comment: [Right here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#extension-and-options) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#url-redirect-to-a-secure-endpoint). I think perhaps you're getting confused with the reads from ApacheModRewrite.txt and IISUrlRewrite.xml. These aren't necessary components for using rewrite, these are simply examples that you can read existing rewrite definition file formats from Apache and IIS. It's certainly not a requirement that you use such files.

Comment: Yes you're right. I was confused by those XML files. So, let me try it. Thank you.